# UI based role management asp.net core 5.0 razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I implemented identity and authorization with razor pages in asp.net 5.0 razor pages and i am able to access this roles directly from the database. How do i created a **UI to manage users and their roles**?
Anyone can guide into useful resource

Comment: I am new to asp.net so worked this out through the documentation but now am stuck at creating a UI for managing the roles and users

Comment: Hi @herbert ichama, Did you want to make a role based authentication?Something like different roles could access different page?

Comment: I wanted a user management UI where a super admin can manage all the users and changing their roles, assigning them roles based on changes in an organization

Answer (score 1):

Although there is built-in UI in ASP.NET Core and you can easily add it to your project, you can also customize it as you desire. Here is a great article on this matter which walks you through on details of creating UI for user and membership management in ASP.NET Core:

[Custom User Management in ASP.NET Core MVC with Identity](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/)